# R how to split text file with multiple space into a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a text file containing characters like this (some of them have multiple spaces between two characters):

```
a b c d  e     f     g  A B C D  E    F    G
```

I want to split them into a 2-row data frame like this:

```
  H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7
1 a  b  c  d  e  f  g
2 A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```

Anyone has idea how to achieve this?

Comment: The pattern to split is not clear.  Between 'e', 'f' and 'g' there is multiple spaces while between 'g' and upper case 'A', not that much.

Comment: Based on the expected output, may be `read.table(text=sub("(?<=[a-z])\\s+(?=[A-Z])", "\n", str1, perl = TRUE), header = FALSE)`

Comment: Exactly that's why I am bit confused how should i split

Comment: If you use the code above, it splits as you showed.  But, if there are other patterns, then you need to show

Comment: Can you provide a better example of your data? What you want to put in the first and in the second row of your output? Upper and lower cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `strsplit` and then cast as a 2-row `matrix` (and optionally as `data.frame`)

```
ss <- c("a b c d  e     f     g  A B C D  E    F    G")

as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit(ss, "\\s+")), nrow = 2, byrow = T))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#2  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `read.table` after creating a new line character  in the string between the lower case letter and upper case letter

```
read.table(text=sub("(?<=[a-z])\\s+(?=[A-Z])", "\n", str1,
             perl = TRUE), header = FALSE, col.names = paste0("H", 1:7))
#  H1 H2 H3 H4 H5 H6 H7
#1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#2  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```

If the pattern is to split at space after every `n` word

```
read.table(text = gsub("((\\S+\\s+){6}\\S+)\\s+", "\\1\n", str2), 
        header = FALSE, col.names = paste0("H", 1:7))
```

---

If this is based on any particular number of characters, we can use `scan` and then wrap it with `matrix` as @Maurits Evers showed

```
matrix(scan(text=str1, what = "", quiet = TRUE), ncol=7, byrow = TRUE)
```

#### data

```
str1 <- 'a b c d  e     f     g  A B C D  E    F    G'
str2 <- paste(str1, str1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two methods making use of `stringr`, part of the `tidyverse`. `str_split` lets you split by a pattern, in this case `"\\s+"`. Setting `simplify = T` makes it return a matrix. To shape how you want, you can create a matrix from *that* matrix with `nrow = 2`.

```r
txt <- "a b c d  e     f     g  A B C D  E    F    G"
mtx <- stringr::str_split(txt, "\\s+", simplify = T)
as.data.frame(matrix(mtx, nrow = 2, byrow = T))
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#> 1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#> 2  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```

Another approach is to extract rather than split. `str_extract_all` lets you extract all matches of a regex, and optionally returns a matrix. Here I extracted lowercase letters and uppercase letters into separate matrices and `rbind`ed them.

```r
lower <- stringr::str_extract_all(txt, "[a-z]", simplify = T)
upper <- stringr::str_extract_all(txt, "[A-Z]", simplify = T)
as.data.frame(rbind(lower, upper))
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#> 1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#> 2  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```

You could also skip the `lower` & `upper` creating and do this in one step:

```r
as.data.frame(rbind(
  stringr::str_extract_all(txt, "[a-z]", simplify = T),
  stringr::str_extract_all(txt, "[A-Z]", simplify = T)
))
#>   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7
#> 1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g
#> 2  A  B  C  D  E  F  G
```